# Webserver losing traffic

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have my e-commerce application running on Ubuntu 12.0.4 on Tomcat 7 servlet. I get around 7000000 hits everyday on this webserver.

However I suspect that the webserver is discarding some traffic (sending 503 responses) to a fair bit of traffic.

Is there a way to know (through some log file on the server) how much traffic it has discarded due to it being busy?

Comment: You can check in the log files of your server, there you can find alot of information if that's happening.

Comment: any specific log file to check. there are a lot of log files.

Comment: This isn't exactly off-topic here as it's an Ubuntu server but it would be a better fit on StackOverflow. [These](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8825618) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6299086) questions might address your issue, or at least point you in the right direction. SO even has a `http-status-code-503` [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-503), too.